# Converting a small hexadecimal String into a integer

Tags: java, integer, hex, converters, decoding

I'm trying to convert a small string of hexadecimal numbers into a array of integers, not very successfully until now. I have tried to find such problems on multiple websites, but most came up with the hexadecimal number simply being to large, which is not the case here. Current code:

```
static String decode(String message) {
        int indexC = 0;
        int asciiCode = 0;
        String [] codeArray = message.split(" ");
        int [] asciiArray = new int[4];

        while (indexC < codeArray.length){
            asciiCode = Integer.parseInt(codeArray[indexC]);
            asciiArray[indexC] = asciiCode;
        }
            for (int i = 0; i < asciiArray.length; i++){
        System.out.println(asciiArray[i]);  
            }
    }
```

I do get a result for the system.out.println but instead of 4 numbers i'd expect, it prints the same (hex) numbers that i started with (in this case: 44 74 71 20)

I am not allowed to include extra libraries or packages, i can only work with codes and classes i create myself. The point of my code is to get the decimal values. the println is only to check what i got (but if somebody know how to print that line correctly, please respond as well ;) ).

(little more background info: i'm building a simple encryptor for text, i'm working on the decoder now, and i need the ascii values connected to the hexadecimal numbers)

Comment: this is not the Full code, only what i believe is slightly relevant, if you think it's usefull to see the full code, I can upload it.

Comment: so the solution is to place ",16" behind my variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the conversion method [`Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) with a radix, (which is 16 for Hex), so you need to change this line

```
asciiCode = Integer.parseInt(codeArray[indexC]);
```

to

```
asciiCode = Integer.parseInt(codeArray[indexC], 16);
```

The reason why you get the same numbers out is because if you don't provide the radix then it defaults to 10.

Comment: you're great, this helped out a lot... it actually fixed the whole code!

Answer (score 1):

`[I@221a5d08` is is the string representation of the array object itself not the content of the array.

If you want to print its content, use [`Arrays.toString(int [] a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29):

`System.out.println(Arrays.toString(asciiArray));`

If you're not allowed to use this method you can implement a simple for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < asciiArray.length; i++)
    System.out.print(asciiArry[i]);
```

Comment: when i do this, i get a error saying "Arrays can not be resolved"

Comment: @user2984993 Add the import `java.util.Arrays`

Comment: i'm sorry to say, but i'm not allowed to do that, i'm only allowed to use libraries provided... i'll add that to the question

Comment: provided by who? That is a standard java library

Comment: @user2984993 If you can't do that, then loop through the array and print out the values: `for (int index = 0; index < asciiArray.length; index++){System.out.println(asciiArray[index]);}` or some variation on that

Comment: I know, i'm not allowed to include any, only those provided by my school

Comment: @user2984993 And what's provided by your school ?

Comment: @Quincunx, thanks, did not think that one up... but it does not change the numbers, it stays hexadecimal (added to question)

Comment: @ZouZou: practicly: nothing

Answer (score 0):

You're printing the address of the array, a common mistake. Use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(asciiArray))` instead.

Comment: when i do this, i get a error saying "Arrays can not be resolved"